# Email address validation fails when domain name has a hyphen

Tags: java, regex, validation, email

I have an email address validation regex Which I use in the code like this:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String lineIwant = "myname@asl.ramco-group.com";
      String emailreg = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
      Boolean b = lineIwant.matches(emailreg);

      if (b == false) {
        System.out.println("Address is Invalid");
      }else if(b == true){
        System.out.println("Address is Valid");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

On this specific email address in the example, the Boolean returns false while this is a valid customer email address.

I am suspecting it is because of the hyphen between `ramco` and `group` because when I remove it the Boolean returns true.

How can I change my regex to accommodate such an email address?

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel - use something like [`EmailValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/javadocs/api-1.4.0/).

Comment: For your Info I had already Looked at that question and taht regex does not Validate either on this specific email ID

Comment: One of approaches [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/).

Comment: @DuncanJones: Do you mind writing an answer?

Comment: I didn't agree with the duplicate, so I've reopened. I don't understand the down-votes either, since you've supplied good example code and described your goals clearly. Up-vote from me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your regex is not allowing a `-` after the `@` sign, so

```
String emailreg = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

would "fix" this specific problem. But Email addresses are much more complicated than that. Validating them using a regex is not a good idea. Check out @DuncanJones' comment.

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend you don't try to solve this problem yourself. Instead, rely on a well-tested solution such as [`EmailValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/javadocs/api-1.4.0/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html) from [commons-validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator).

For example:

```
EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(emailAddressString);
```

Comment: EmailValidator also gives you the option of excluding local email addresses so that the top level domain must be present, which was a requirement for me.

Comment: EmailValidator seems deprecated, it doesn't recognize latest TLD.

Comment: @Antares Can you give an example?

Comment: I was using EmailValidator 1.4, and it was considering "abcd@domain.email" as an invalid email address.

Comment: @Antares Looks like this is known about, see [VALIDATOR-305](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VALIDATOR-305). So I guess you are stuck until a new release is made.

Answer (score 3):

there are many regexp validation strings, that you can use. Like [here](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

but it is realy nescesary to have Optimal solution?  Don't need you only sub optimal solution that covers 99.9999% used adresses?

read this 
[article](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `\\-` to that section of the regex string after the `@`.

The `\\` is an escape telling Java that you do not want to use the dash as it's normally used to show the difference between two values. So like this...

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9\\-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

**Update**

Tim acknowledged in the comments that the escape is not necessary!

And a quick tip of my own is you might want to use `\w` in replace of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` so you don't have to keep writing that over and over. And finally get familiar with [this site](http://regexpal.com/). Once you start using regex it's a great help.

Comment: Not quite. First, the dash is used to denote a *range* between two characters, not a difference (but perhaps that's what you meant). Second, if the dash is the last character (or the first) in a character class, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Learned something new today, thanks Tim I had no idea. I always play it safe and add my escapes but that's a great tip thanks.

Comment: Note: `\w` is `A-Za-z0-9_`, `\w` is superset of `\d`.

Comment: `\w` is great and all, since it shorten the regex, but the thing is that people keep forgetting that `_` and digits are included. And its meaning, although usually consistent between languages, might receive an upgrade to match Unicode characters, like in .NET regular expression. I don't object to its use, though.